# Get the least value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

For example we have this code:

```
var json = {
    "user1" : {
        "id" : 3
    },
    "user2" : {
        "id" : 6
    },
    "user3" : {
        "id" : 1
    }
}
```

I want to get the least id in JavaScript:

```
"user3" : {
        "id" : 1
}
```

How to get the least id in object via JavaScript?

Please Help!

Thanks ;)

Comment: There is no JSON there. That is a JavaScript object. You can do this with a loop (which should be trivial to reason about), but it would be *easier* (and a better way to deal with sequences) if it looked like: `var arr = [{id: 3, name: "user1"}, {id: 6, name: "user2"}, ..]`.

Comment: Not sure what the downvotes pertain to, the question is simple and straight forward. As for JSON, that stands for JavaScript Object Notation @user2246674

Comment: @AlexisAbril JSON is *textual data* which is *based on* ECMAScript literal syntax. There is only JavaScript in the given post - no JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could do something like..

```
var min = null;
var obj = null;
for (var i in json) {
    if (json.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        if (min === null || json[i].id < min) {
            min = json[i].id;
            obj = json[i];
        }
    }
}
```